# How do I catch permission denied errors from the glob operator?

Tags: linux, perl, bash

The following simple Perl script will list the contents of a directory, with the directory listed as an argument to the script.  How, on a Linux system can I capture permission denied errors?  Currently if this script is run on a directory that the user does not have read permissions to, nothing happens in the terminal.

```
#!/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub print_dir {
foreach ( glob "@_/*" )
  {print "$_\n"};
}

print_dir @ARGV
```

Comment: What you're asking for would be atypical behavior from a `glob`.  `stat` can tell you whether you have access to the directory.

Comment: I understand that glob has no awareness of the user's permissions, but  I assume the shell is returning an error to the script but it isn't getting printed, is that not correct?  I am interested in how to catch the error from the shell and print it.

Comment: I see what you mean now, I just tried echo /root/* and it does not return an error in the shell.  Thank you.

Comment: *“When a tree falls in a lonely forest, and no animal is near by to hear it, does it make a sound?”* — If you pass `glob` a pattern that does not match, how do you handle permission errors? The question seems empty to me.

Comment: @amon, the distinction is that the pattern may match but the current user doesn't have privilege to distinguish.  Ideally `glob` should return an error in cases where it cannot determine whether or not there is a match.

Comment: That's right Brian, In fact I know the pattern matches because I am giving directories that are created during the OS install as args to test this, such as /root and /tmp.  /root returns nothing even though I know it has content.

Answer (score 5):

The `glob` function does not have much error control, except that `$!` is set if the last glob fails:

```
glob "A/*"; # No read permission for A => "Permission denied"
print "Error globbing A: $!\n" if ($!);
```

If the glob succeeds to find something later, `$!` will not be set, though. For example `glob "*/*"` would not report an error even if it couldn't list the contents for a directory.

The `bsd_glob` function from the standard [`File::Glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) module allows setting a flag to enable reliable error reporting:

```
use File::Glob qw(bsd_glob);
bsd_glob("*/*", File::Glob::GLOB_ERR);
print "Error globbing: $!\n" if (File::Glob::GLOB_ERROR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use File::Find, which is a core module and is able to control everything on a file.

```
#!perl
use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
find {
    wanted => sub {
        return if not -r $_; # skip if not readable
        say $_;
    },
    no_chdir => 1,
}, @ARGV;
```